# Foursquare not returning all attributes from a search

Tags: javascript, http, get, foursquare

I'm making requests to Foursquare using

```
GET https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search
```

in an attempt to get the "price" attribute. However, it doesn't seem to return all the listed attributes that this docs page details.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/search

This is the object that I am receiving:

```
   id: '4c93ae9594a0236aea808512',
   name: 'China Garden',
   contact: {},
   location: [Object],
   categories: [Array],
   verified: false,
   stats: [Object],
   hasMenu: true,
   menu: [Object],
   allowMenuUrlEdit: true,
   beenHere: [Object],
   specials: [Object],
   referralId: 'v-1516988384',
   venueChains: [],
   hasPerk: false
```

As you can see, the price attribute (along with some others) is not part of the response object. These are also the parameters I'm using to make the search:

```
var params = {
    "near": "exmouth uk",
    "categoryId": catID,
    "intent": "browse",
    "limit": 50,
    "time": "any",
    "day": "any",
};
```

Does anybody know why these are the only attributes that are returned?

Comment: My initial guess was this info wasn't available for some venues, so it wasn't part of the response. But I've cross-referenced venues on Foursquare.com (which show a price) and the API responses. And the API responses lack the `price` object even for venues which show the price on Foursquare.com. However, if you request the details for one of those venues, the `price` object is present. So it seems `price` is only available when requesting venue details. Not ideal, but it seems you'd need to request the details for every venue you want price info for.

Comment: =Brett. This looks like a documentation error. I'm only seeing price returned for the /details API as well.

Comment: This was exactly the problem! The only way of getting the price object is by searching each venue individually

Comment: Try this new [`/search/recommendations` endpoint](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/recommendations).

Answer (score 0):

There's a new [`/search/recommendations` endpoint](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/recommendations) that sounds like it will do what you want.

For one, it allows querying on params like `near`, `categoryId`, `limit`, `localTime`, `localDay`, and more.

And the response contains `price`, and more.

Here's an example of a response:

```js
[{
  "displayType": "venue",
  "venue": {
    "id": "4fa445c8e4b0baf7cc71e811",
    "name": "Boudoir",
    "contact": {
      "phone": "+441382225968",
      "formattedPhone": "+44 1382 225968"
    },
    "location": {
      "address": "1 Temple Lane",
      "lat": 56.459587391243105,
      "lng": -2.978718040375153,
      "labeledLatLngs": [{
        "label": "display",
        "lat": 56.459587391243105,
        "lng": -2.978718040375153
      }],
      "postalCode": "DD1 4HA",
      "cc": "GB",
      "city": "Dundee",
      "state": "Dundee City",
      "country": "United Kingdom",
      "formattedAddress": [
        "1 Temple Lane",
        "Dundee",
        "Dundee City",
        "DD1 4HA",
        "United Kingdom"
      ]
    },
    "categories": [{
      "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d146941735",
      "name": "Deli / Bodega",
      "pluralName": "Delis / Bodegas",
      "shortName": "Deli / Bodega",
      "icon": {
        "prefix": "https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/food/deli_",
        "suffix": ".png"
      },
      "primary": true
    }],
    "verified": false,
    "stats": {
      "checkinsCount": 73,
      "usersCount": 46,
      "tipCount": 0
    },
    "url": "http://www.boudoir.wickedweb.biz",
    "price": {
      "tier": 3,
      "message": "Expensive",
      "currency": "£"
    },
    "dislike": false,
    "ok": false,
    "allowMenuUrlEdit": true,
    "beenHere": {
      "count": 0,
      "marked": false,
      "lastCheckinExpiredAt": 0
    }
  },
  "id": "5a86bea63b830731dbaff394",
  "photo": {
    "id": "51d8959a498ebc1f8cfe6ca1",
    "createdAt": 1373148570,
    "prefix": "https://igx.4sqi.net/img/general/",
    "suffix": "/2773213_EBnYq-AmD-arj7VH3pP47B7HMi1lP2LYdb76CSsJJ9o.jpg",
    "width": 720,
    "height": 960,
    "visibility": "public"
  },
  "snippets": {
    "count": 1,
    "items": [{}]
  }
}]
```